# Select Max value from Current Date

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to insert value in Database start by 1 and it will be again start from 1 when start new date 
for ex. today is 27-Apr-2018 Counting start from 1,2,3,4,5 every time insert new number in database on button click But when start 28-Apr it will again set on 1(0)

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing you can do by first fire select query on your database using current Date and see if there any record exists or not if its exist then insert record with incrementing that value. And if it not exists then start by inserting 1 as initial value. So from next day it will first check for any record exists for today's date. if then it will increment that value else insert new value.

check below Code

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX([VALUE]) as MaxValue FROM Table1 where MyDate=GETDATE()";
            object maxValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 if (maxValue != DBNull.Value)
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(maxValue) + 1;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO  Table1 ([VALUES],MyDate) VALUES (" + value + ",GETDATE())";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO  Table1 ([VALUES],MyDate) VALUES (1, GETDATE())";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Make appropriate code change in this.

Comment: Hi thank you so much sir for reply and giving me your valuable  time can please review and make it correct sorry for english :)

Comment: SqlConnection conrecipt = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
        conrecipt.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select COALESCE (MAX(OPDNo),0)+1 from OPDRegistration Where="+ DateTime.Today, conrecipt);

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        conrecipt.Close();

        Label3.Text = i.ToString();

Comment: check above code and make appropriate change in the code.

Comment: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
i get this error

Comment: have make you change in above code. it seems your connection string is not proper.

Comment: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
 Now come this error after change string

Comment: Sir i cant comment because of long Creator so i post in answer please review sir

Comment: int value = Convert.ToInt32(maxValue) + 1; in this line sir